# c function chaining possible?

Tags: c

I was wondering if it is possible in C (89/90) to chain function calls, and where it is defined in the [C spec](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt). I assume this isn't possible since a google search reveals no mention of it.

I thought of this because of a related conversation with a friend of mine where he told me that given a function returning a struct, you cannot perform any operations on said struct within the same statement; instead, you have to assign the result of the function to a variable, and then manipulate the struct via the variable instead of directly from the function result itself. This leads me to believe that you can't chain functions either, but I can't seem to find these limitations discussed in the spec.

Edit : Sorry, I should have been specific on the return value. Assuming the function returns a function pointer, is it possible to dereference and call the result within the same statement, in fluent fashion?

For example, assuming `getFunc` returns a function pointer :

```
(*getFunc(getFuncParam))(otherFuncParam)
```

Or in the `struct` case, assuming a `struct` with an `int` member called `count`:

```
funcReturnsStruct(param).count++
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what function chaining looks like in C:

```
post_process(process(pre_process(data)));
```

Obviously, your friend is wrong. As long as the functions cooperate by accepting and returning the same type of value you can chain the calls all you like.

Contrast this with something like

```
data.pre_process().process().post_process();
```

The big difference is that in C (which has no encapsulation, hence no classes) *functions* have center stage while in more modern OO languages it's *objects* that get more attention.

**Update:** Sure it's possible to chain no matter what each function might return. For example:

```
int increase(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

typedef int (*increase_fp)(int);

increase_fp get_increase() {
    return increase;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", get_increase()(1));
    return 0;
}
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/oAl2b).

Comment: `void*` is a C programmer's encapsulation ;)

Comment: @pmr `void *` is a C programmer's `Object`. Encapsulation is `struct foo;` (i.e. forward declaration) and only using `struct foo *`.

Comment: I should have been more specific; I edited my post accordingly. I meant in a fluent fashion. For example, assuming getFunc returns a function pointer : (*getFunc()).doSomething()

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, and you don't even have to use `*` because `()` on a function pointer type both dereferences the pointer and makes the call. In general, you can "chain" anything you can imagine.

Comment: Ahhhhh... yes, because of pointer decay, perfect! :D I wonder why my search for C function chaining returned nothing...

Answer (score 3):

> a friend of mine where he told me that given a function returning a struct, you cannot perform any operations on said struct within the same statement

Your friend is correct in the sense that the return value of a function cannot be the target of an assignment (it's not an lvalue).  IOW, you can't do something like

```
int foo(void) { int x = 5; return x; }
...
foo() = 6;
```

However, if the return type of a function is a struct or a union, you *can* apply the component selection operator to the return value, such as

```
int x = foo().memb;
```

Similarly, if the return type of the function is a pointer to a struct or a union, you can write

```
int x = foo()->memb;
```

And if the return value is a pointer to another function, you can call that other function like so:

```
int bar(int x) { ... }
int (*foo)(int x) { return bar; }
int x = foo(x)(y); // or (*foo(x))(y) -- the result of foo(x) is 
                   // called with the argument y
```

although anyone who has to maintain or debug your code may beat you severely for it.

What you *cannot* do is something like

```
foo().memb= ...;
foo()->memb = ...;
```

which wouldn't make sense anyway, because the lifetime of the value returned by `foo` ends when the statement ends - you wouldn't be able to retrieve that modified value.

Comment: Oh, so you *can't* do foo().memb=x  or foo()->memb=x because functions don't return an lvalue... got it. However, it would make sense to do this if foo(int hash) did a lookup and returned a struct from a hash table. I believe a work-around here would be to return a pointer to the struct, which can then be dereferenced and it's member modified. Ex : (*foo(hash)).memb++ should work?

Comment: Yeah, that works, although you should *really* store and test the pointer value before attempting to dereference it; if `foo(hash)` returns a NULL or invalid pointer value, you're going to have an access violation. Unless you *know* `foo(hash)` cannot return an invalid pointer, don't write code like that.  As with most things in C, just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is wrong.

If we have:

```
struct Point3
{
   float x, y, z;
};

const Point3 * point3_get_origin(void);
```

then you can certainly do:

```
printf("the origin's y coordinate is %f\n", point3_get_origin()->y);
```

The function returns a value of the given type, so the call of the function can be used wherever such a value is needed in an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
typedef void (*CALLBACK)(void);

CALLBACK getCallback();

void test()
{
    getCallback()();
}
```

It compiles with no warning in GCC 4.6.1 (default std).

Answer (score 0):

There's a much faster and easier way to answer this than posting here: try it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
        int a;
} s;

struct s * getS() {
        s.a = 13;
        return &s;
}

int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {
        printf("%d\n", getS()->a);
        return 0;
}
```

```
% gcc test.c -o test -Wall -pedantic
% ./test
13
%
```

Not so much as a pedantic warning. Expected output. Looks like it's perfectly fine. However, as has been pointed out, it would be better to store the return value and check for errors.