# How make chaining functions in c?

Tags: c

In c++ you can chaining functions returning a reference to object like `function1().function2().function3()`.

Is there any way to make that in c? maybe using function pointers?
I made a little example, it was the only way I could think of.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct date
{
    unsigned day;
    struct date *(*func_print)(struct date*);
     struct date *(*func_assign)(struct date*,unsigned);
};

struct date *create_date(void)
{
    struct date *obj = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
    return obj ? obj : NULL;
}

struct date *assign(struct date *this, unsigned value){
    this->day = value;
    return this;
}
struct date* print(struct date *this){
    printf("%d\n",this->day);
    return this;
}

int main()
{
    struct date *my = create_date();    
    my->func_print = print;
    my->func_assign = assign;
    my->func_assign(my,20)->func_print(my);

    free(my);

}
```

Comment: Can be done the similar way if `functionX()` is returning a `struct` with a function pointer as a member.

Comment: @Jabberwocky that seems to be the consensus for the meaning of *chaining functions*, see [C function chaining possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484005/c-function-chaining-possible) and other similar SO questions. Which differs from OP's example, that more closely resembles *method chaining*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c function chaining possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484005/c-function-chaining-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really sure you want this?

```
struct decl1 {
    struct decl2 (*function2)();
};

struct decl2 {
    struct decl3 (*function3)();
};

void function3()
{
}

struct decl2 function2()
{
    // ...
    struct decl2 one { function3 };
    return one;
}

struct decl1 function1()
{
    // ...
    struct decl1 one { function2 };
    return one;
}
```

But you can't bind any arguments so there is no way for `function2` to operate on the same object as `function` unless you pass it again.

If you're willing to dive into a little bit of assembly you can make this work by writing function bodies to the structs. Don't do this. The maintenance programmer will hate your guts.